# Button for updating a blog post

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-urls, django-2.2

I've a trouble to create correctly a button based on Bootstrap 4.3 with which activates the update of a post.
I've created this **view**:

```
def updatePost(request, slug_post=None):
    update_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug_post=slug_post)
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=update_post)
    if form.is_valid():
        update_post = form.save(commit=False)
        update_post.slug_post = slugify(update_post.title)
        update_post.save()
        return redirect('post_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    template = 'blog/editing/create_post.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and this **path**:

```
path("blog/<str:slug_post>/update/", views.updatePost, name='update_post'),
```

But when I use this **button**:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2" href="{% url 'update_post' %}">Update</a>
```

I see this error message:

> Reverse for 'update_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s)
> tried: ['blog/(?P<slug_post>[^/]+)/update/$']

The strange thing is that if I write the link to the update into the address bar I can update my post. For example: I've this link to a post: `/blog/title-slug-post/`. If I digit `/blog/title-slug-post/update/` it is possible for me to update the post.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: In your <button> the url should have a slug right ? something like href="{% url 'update_post' 'title-slug-post'  %}"
As I have seen the url call should be something like 
`<a href="{% url 'name' 'some_string_containing_relevant_data' %}">pagename</a>`

Comment: But even when you've fixed this it still won't work because `button` elements don't have `href` attributes. They are part of forms which have an `action` attribute which is the URL to submit to.

Comment: Yes I've correct my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `slug_post` argument in the url template tag. Right now it doesn't know what slug you want and raises an error.

```
{% url 'update_post' slug_post='title-slug-post' %}
```

If you pass the BlogPost object in the context you can also format it this way.

```
{% url 'update_post' slug_post=blog_post.slug_post %}
```